# Assign JSON field to model variable in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am having my json like:

```
{
   "name": "Rahul",
   "2or4": 2,

}
```

Here,

How can I assign my model variable : twoOrFour to jason field value "2or4"
as we can not have variable start with integer.

I am new to django. I am using dJango-rest-framework for this api.

Comment: Why not, simply, rename the JSON field `2or4` to `twoOrFour`?

Comment: actually that is not in my hand :(. Do I have any other option apart from it?

Comment: If you are writing backend for an API call, its better to change the API call to return "2or4" as an alias to "twoOrFour". I think you should leave the model alone

Comment: @Ramast: I am writing backend for API call. Can you please tell me how can I have a alias.

Comment: I've placed my answer below, let me know if its not clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using djangorestframework you will need to override to_representation function in your serializer

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior

should be something like this

```
def to_representation(self, obj)
    serialized_data = super(SerializerClassName, self).to_representation(obj)
    serialized_data["2or4"] = serialized_data["twoOrFour"]
    //Remove the old field name
    del serialized_data["twoOrFour"]
    return serialized_data
```

This code should work where SerializerClassName is the class name of your serializer

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `twoOrFour` to your JSON object. For example:

```
import json

data = {'name': 'Rahul', '2or4': 2}

data = json.loads(data) # convert to Python dict
data['twoOrFour'] = data['2or4'] # append twoOrFour
data = json.dumps(data) # convert back to JSON object
```

Now the JSON object has `twoOrFour` field. Hope it works.